# Bootstrap Typeahead only displaying first letter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datasource, typeahead

I'm having a tough time getting Twitter Bootstrap's Typeahead to work. Typeahead is only matching the first letter of an input. My results in the typeahead box looks something like

```
n
n
n
N
N
n.
```

My code is

```
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], "data-provide" => "typeahead", "data-source" => '["USA", "Canada","Mexico"]' %>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7):

Check the combination of quotes that's output in your html for the data-source attribute. I was having the same problem with the following snippet of code.

```
<input type="text" name="test" id="test" class="span2" data-provide="typeahead" 
data-items="4" data-source="['thisone','another','zzzz']">
```

changing to the following, which I've seen in other examples, didn't fix it

```
data-source="["thisone","another","zzzz"]"
```

but switching to single quotes around the attribute value and double-quotes for the searchable elements fixed it. **This works**.

```
data-source='["thisone","another","zzzz"]'
```

Comment: Nice. The First option (data-source="["thisone","another","zzzz"]") did the trick for me. Thx.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who is getting this problem when using a source function (i.e. ajax call to your server):

use:

```
process(JSON.parse(data));
```

instead of:

```
process(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

I just tried your code, and it worked for me. When I changed the quotes to be like this though, I was getting the issue you're having:

```
"['USA', 'Canada','Mexico']"
```

I was running into a similar problem, it's slightly different than your issue, but it might help others. What was happening to me is that the JSON I was passing to typeahead was being interpreted as a character array. So if I passed in:

```
["USA", "Canada","Mexico"]
```

It would interpret it as an array of 26 characters, thus the results typeahead was giving me were single characters.

In my case, it was because I was making an ajax call and I didn't set the dataType to 'json'. In your case that isn't the problem, but hopefully this gets you moving towards a solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = "";
$.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/getdirverandpass.php',
        success: function (result) {
            data = JSON.parse(result);
        },
        async: false
});

 $("#nav-search-input").typeahead({source: data, updater: function (a) {
            $("#nav-search-input").focus();
            return a
}});
```

please use this 
JSON.parse(result);