# Twitter Bootstrap Typeahead only populating letter "a"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete, typeahead

so I'm trying to populate a list of countries using bootstrap typeahead. I want the person to start typing in a text field the country they live in and then it will show the options to choose from.

Initially, I had the data-source set to a variable which is a huge array of countries that are strings. 
I was only getting one singular "a" to show up when I would type in "a" by itself. Literally only the letter a.

then I changed the source to directly hold the array itself and the array was held inside of two single quotes. now the when i hit any key it comes up with results, but literally when i put "a" into the text box, the result is:
a
A
a
A
A
A
a
a
a
a 
or something to that sort... its weird. here is my code:

In my jsp here is the portion inside of the "head":

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Disti Tool Wireframe</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/disti.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/styling.css" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" />

</head>
```

here is the body of the code:

```
<div id = "label">Country:</div>
<div id ="txtentry">
    <input type="text" id="country"  data-provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off" class="span3" data-source='["Afghanistan", "Akrotiri", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa",
    "Andorra",
    "Angola",
    "Anguilla",
    "Antarctica",
    "Antigua and Barbuda",
    "Argentina",
    "Armenia",
    "Aruba",
    "Ashmore and Cartier Islands",
    "Australia",
    "Austria",
    "Azerbaijan",
    "Bahamas, The",
    "Bahrain",
    "Bangladesh"
    "Barbados"
    "Bassas da India",
    "Belarus",
    "Belgium",
    "Belize",
    "Benin",
    "Bermuda",
    "Bhutan",
    "Bolivia",
    "Bosnia and Herzegovina",
    "Botswana",
    "Bouvet Island",
    "Brazil",
    "British Indian Ocean Territory",
    "British Virgin Islands",
    "Brunei",
    "Bulgaria",
    "Burkina Faso",
    "Burma",
    "Burundi",
    "Cambodia",
    "Cameroon",
    "Canada",
    "Cape Verde",
    "Cayman Islands",
    "Central African Republic",
    "Chad",
    "Chile",
    "China",
    "Christmas Island",
    "Clipperton Island",
    "Cocos (Keeling) Islands",
    "Colombia",
    "Comoros",
    "Congo, Democratic Republic of the",
    "Congo, Republic of the",
    "Cook Islands",
    "Coral Sea Islands",
    "Costa Rica",
    "Croatia",
    "Cuba",
    "Cyprus",
    "Czech Republic",
    "Denmark",
    "Dhekelia",
    "Djibouti",
    "Dominica",
    "Dominican Republic",
    "Ecuador",
    "Egypt",
    "El Salvador",
    "Equatorial Guinea",
    "Eritrea",
    "Estonia",
    "Ethiopia",
    "Europa Island",
    "Falkland Islands (Islas Malvinas)",
    "Faroe Islands",
    "Fiji",
    "Finland",
    "France",
    "French Guiana",
    "French Polynesia",
    "French Southern and Antarctic Lands",
    "Gabon",
    "Gambia, The",
    "Gaza Strip",
    "Georgia",
    "Germany",
    "Ghana",
    "Gibraltar",
    "Glorioso Islands",
    "Greece",
    "Greenland",
    "Grenada",
    "Guadeloupe",
    "Guam",
    "Guatemala",
    "Guernsey",
    "Guinea",
    "Guinea-Bissau",
    "Guyana",
    "Haiti",
    "Heard Island and McDonald Islands",
    "Holy See (Vatican City)",
    "Honduras",
    "Hong Kong",
    "Hungary",
    "Iceland",
    "India",
    "Indonesia",
    "Iran",
    "Iraq",
    "Ireland",
    "Isle of Man",
    "Israel",
    "Italy",
    "Jamaica",
    "Jan Mayen",
    "Japan",
    "Jersey",
    "Jordan",
    "Juan de Nova Island",
    "Kazakhstan",
    "Kenya",
    "Kiribati",
    "Korea, North",
    "Korea, South",
    "Kuwait",
    "Kyrgyzstan",
    "Laos",
    "Latvia",
    "Lebanon",
    "Lesotho",
    "Liberia",
    "Libya",
    "Liechtenstein",
    "Lithuania",
    "Luxembourg",
    "Macau",
    "Macedonia",
    "Madagascar",
    "Malawi",
    "Malaysia",
    "Maldives",
    "Mali",
    "Malta",
    "Marshall Islands",
    "Martinique",
    "Mauritania",
    "Mauritius",
    "Mayotte",
    "Mexico",
    "Micronesia, Federated States of",
    "Moldova",
    "Monaco",
    "Mongolia",
    "Montserrat",
    "Morocco",
    "Mozambique",
    "Namibia",
    "Nauru",
    "Navassa Island",
    "Nepal",
    "Netherlands",
    "Netherlands Antilles",
    "New Caledonia",
    "New Zealand",
    "Nicaragua",
    "Niger",
    "Nigeria",
    "Niue",
    "Norfolk Island",
    "Northern Mariana Islands",
    "Norway",
    "Oman",
    "Pakistan",
    "Palau",
    "Panama",
    "Papua New Guinea",
    "Paracel Islands",
    "Paraguay",
    "Peru",
    "Philippines",
    "Pitcairn Islands",
    "Poland",
    "Portugal",
    "Puerto Rico",
    "Qatar",
    "Reunion",
    "Romania",
    "Russia",
    "Rwanda",
    "Saint Helena",
    "Saint Kitts and Nevis",
    "Saint Lucia",
    "Saint Pierre and Miquelon",
    "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines",
    "Samoa",
    "San Marino",
    "Sao Tome and Principe",
    "Saudi Arabia",
    "Senegal",
    "Serbia and Montenegro",
    "Seychelles",
    "Sierra Leone",
    "Singapore",
    "Slovakia",
    "Slovenia",
    "Solomon Islands",
    "Somalia",
    "South Africa",
    "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands",
    "Spain",
    "Spratly Islands",
    "Sri Lanka",
    "Sudan",
    "Suriname",
    "Svalbard",
    "Swaziland",
    "Sweden",
    "Switzerland",
    "Syria",
    "Taiwan",
    "Tajikistan",
    "Tanzania",
    "Thailand",
    "Timor-Leste",
    "Togo",
    "Tokelau",
    "Tonga",
    "Trinidad and Tobago",
    "Tromelin Island",
    "Tunisia",
    "Turkey",
    "Turkmenistan",
    "Turks and Caicos Islands",
    "Tuvalu",
    "Uganda",
    "Ukraine",
    "United Arab Emirates",
    "United Kingdom",
    "United States",
    "Uruguay",
    "Uzbekistan",
    "Vanuatu",
    "Venezuela",
    "Vietnam",
    "Virgin Islands",
    "Wake Island",
    "Wallis and Futuna",
    "West Bank",
    "Western Sahara",
    "Yemen",
    "Zambia",
    "Zimbabwe" ]'>
</div>
```

and here is what is at the bottom of the body of my code. I have the array in here twice since I was messing with it and was trying to see how I could make it work. I obviously know having the array in there twice is redundant. I'm just debugging.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var location = ["Afghanistan", "Akrotiri", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa",
            "Andorra",
            "Angola",
            "Anguilla",
            "Antarctica",
            "Antigua and Barbuda",
            "Argentina",
            "Armenia",
            "Aruba",
            "Ashmore and Cartier Islands",
            "Australia",
            "Austria",
            "Azerbaijan",
            "Bahamas, The",
            "Bahrain",
            "Bangladesh"
            "Barbados"
            "Bassas da India",
            "Belarus",
            "Belgium",
            "Belize",
            "Benin",
            "Bermuda",
            "Bhutan",
            "Bolivia",
            "Bosnia and Herzegovina",
            "Botswana",
            "Bouvet Island",
            "Brazil",
            "British Indian Ocean Territory",
            "British Virgin Islands",
            "Brunei",
            "Bulgaria",
            "Burkina Faso",
            "Burma",
            "Burundi",
            "Cambodia",
            "Cameroon",
            "Canada",
            "Cape Verde",
            "Cayman Islands",
            "Central African Republic",
            "Chad",
            "Chile",
            "China",
            "Christmas Island",
            "Clipperton Island",
            "Cocos (Keeling) Islands",
            "Colombia",
            "Comoros",
            "Congo, Democratic Republic of the",
            "Congo, Republic of the",
            "Cook Islands",
            "Coral Sea Islands",
            "Costa Rica",
            "Cote d'Ivoire",
            "Croatia",
            "Cuba",
            "Cyprus",
            "Czech Republic",
            "Denmark",
            "Dhekelia",
            "Djibouti",
            "Dominica",
            "Dominican Republic",
            "Ecuador",
            "Egypt",
            "El Salvador",
            "Equatorial Guinea",
            "Eritrea",
            "Estonia",
            "Ethiopia",
            "Europa Island",
            "Falkland Islands (Islas Malvinas)",
            "Faroe Islands",
            "Fiji",
            "Finland",
            "France",
            "French Guiana",
            "French Polynesia",
            "French Southern and Antarctic Lands",
            "Gabon",
            "Gambia, The",
            "Gaza Strip",
            "Georgia",
            "Germany",
            "Ghana",
            "Gibraltar",
            "Glorioso Islands",
            "Greece",
            "Greenland",
            "Grenada",
            "Guadeloupe",
            "Guam",
            "Guatemala",
            "Guernsey",
            "Guinea",
            "Guinea-Bissau",
            "Guyana",
            "Haiti",
            "Heard Island and McDonald Islands",
            "Holy See (Vatican City)",
            "Honduras",
            "Hong Kong",
            "Hungary",
            "Iceland",
            "India",
            "Indonesia",
            "Iran",
            "Iraq",
            "Ireland",
            "Isle of Man",
            "Israel",
            "Italy",
            "Jamaica",
            "Jan Mayen",
            "Japan",
            "Jersey",
            "Jordan",
            "Juan de Nova Island",
            "Kazakhstan",
            "Kenya",
            "Kiribati",
            "Korea, North",
            "Korea, South",
            "Kuwait",
            "Kyrgyzstan",
            "Laos",
            "Latvia",
            "Lebanon",
            "Lesotho",
            "Liberia",
            "Libya",
            "Liechtenstein",
            "Lithuania",
            "Luxembourg",
            "Macau",
            "Macedonia",
            "Madagascar",
            "Malawi",
            "Malaysia",
            "Maldives",
            "Mali",
            "Malta",
            "Marshall Islands",
            "Martinique",
            "Mauritania",
            "Mauritius",
            "Mayotte",
            "Mexico",
            "Micronesia, Federated States of",
            "Moldova",
            "Monaco",
            "Mongolia",
            "Montserrat",
            "Morocco",
            "Mozambique",
            "Namibia",
            "Nauru",
            "Navassa Island",
            "Nepal",
            "Netherlands",
            "Netherlands Antilles",
            "New Caledonia",
            "New Zealand",
            "Nicaragua",
            "Niger",
            "Nigeria",
            "Niue",
            "Norfolk Island",
            "Northern Mariana Islands",
            "Norway",
            "Oman",
            "Pakistan",
            "Palau",
            "Panama",
            "Papua New Guinea",
            "Paracel Islands",
            "Paraguay",
            "Peru",
            "Philippines",
            "Pitcairn Islands",
            "Poland",
            "Portugal",
            "Puerto Rico",
            "Qatar",
            "Reunion",
            "Romania",
            "Russia",
            "Rwanda",
            "Saint Helena",
            "Saint Kitts and Nevis",
            "Saint Lucia",
            "Saint Pierre and Miquelon",
            "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines",
            "Samoa",
            "San Marino",
            "Sao Tome and Principe",
            "Saudi Arabia",
            "Senegal",
            "Serbia and Montenegro",
            "Seychelles",
            "Sierra Leone",
            "Singapore",
            "Slovakia",
            "Slovenia",
            "Solomon Islands",
            "Somalia",
            "South Africa",
            "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands",
            "Spain",
            "Spratly Islands",
            "Sri Lanka",
            "Sudan",
            "Suriname",
            "Svalbard",
            "Swaziland",
            "Sweden",
            "Switzerland",
            "Syria",
            "Taiwan",
            "Tajikistan",
            "Tanzania",
            "Thailand",
            "Timor-Leste",
            "Togo",
            "Tokelau",
            "Tonga",
            "Trinidad and Tobago",
            "Tromelin Island",
            "Tunisia",
            "Turkey",
            "Turkmenistan",
            "Turks and Caicos Islands",
            "Tuvalu",
            "Uganda",
            "Ukraine",
            "United Arab Emirates",
            "United Kingdom",
            "United States",
            "Uruguay",
            "Uzbekistan",
            "Vanuatu",
            "Venezuela",
            "Vietnam",
            "Virgin Islands",
            "Wake Island",
            "Wallis and Futuna",
            "West Bank",
            "Western Sahara",
            "Yemen",
            "Zambia",
            "Zimbabwe" ];

            $('#country').typeahead({source: location});
```

I used to have

```
<input type="text" id="country"  data-provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off" class="span3" data-source="location">
```

referring to my array of countries but this was what produced only a single a as a result in the typeahead.

Please help... is it my placement of jquery/bootstrap sources?
Is something wrong with my jquery call?
I'm very confused here. Thank you.

Comment: I also know there is already a question similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187793/bootstrap-typeahead-only-displaying-first-letter , but I'm not making ajax calls and none of the answers have helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a problem with the array, I made the array smaller and it works now, you can see it here:

**UPDATE**
You forgot some commas in the array the the updated array from js fiddle, at 'Bangladesh' there it is the problem

http://jsfiddle.net/dT5vJ/2/

Please recheck your array

```
  var location = ["Afghanistan", "Akrotiri", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa",
            "Andorra",
            "Angola",
            "Anguilla",
            "Antarctica",
            "Antigua and Barbuda",
            "Argentina",
            "Armenia",
            "Aruba",
            "Ashmore and Cartier Islands",
            "Australia",
            "Austria",
            "Azerbaijan",
            "Bahamas, The" ];
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you know why I might get this error when I fixed the comma problem?? HTTP status 404 - type Status report

message /PDFAdmin/Afghanistan,Akrotiri,Albania,Algeria,American%20Samoa,Andorra,Angola,Anguilla,Antarctica,Antigua%20and%20Barbuda,Argentina,Armenia,Aruba,Ashmore%20and%20Cartier%20Islands,Australia,Austria,Azerbaijan,Bahamas,%20The,Bahrain,Bangladesh,Barbados,Bassas%20da%20India,Belarus,Belgium,Belize,Benin,Bermuda,Bhutan,Bolivia,Bosnia%20and%20Herzegovina,......
description The requested resource is not available.

Comment: Actually, I just removed the array from being referenced and directly placed it in the typeahead call within two single quotes ' '. Thank you so much. This did help.